# Find topojson feature by latitude longitude

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, d3.js, topojson

The demo I'm working on is based on [World tour](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4183330), which uses canvas instead of SVG, so I cannot attach mouse event to country path to find what country was clicked. Is there any way to find which feature contains lat/long I get from mouse coordinates?

```
var canvas = d3.select("canvas")
    .on("mousemove", function() {
        var p = d3.mouse(canvas.node());
        console.log(projection.invert(p)); // which country contains these coordinates?
    });

var countries;
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, 'world-110m.json.txt')
    .defer(d3.tsv, 'world-country-names.tsv')
    .await(function ready(error, world, names) {
        countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features;
    });
```

Comment: Please, share your code or jsfiddle.

Comment: Try using Document.elementFromPoint().

Answer (score 3):

You best option is to create a hidden canvas that mirrors the visible one but draws each country in a different RGB color (a literal "bitmap"), and look up the corresponding feature by the color of the pixel at the mouse cursor's position.

You can see a working example of this [here](http://bl.ocks.org/shawnbot/8cf68782ce1da30acabb). I've kept the bitmap visible so you can see what's happening.

You do have some other options:

1. Use a library (such as [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/)) to do point-in-polygon checks, e.g. with [turf.inside](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_inside.html).
2. As an optimization, construct a [d3.geom.quadtree](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quadtree-Geom) of all of the points in every feature and only perform the point-in-polygon checks for features inside the quadtree leaf node.